# jQuery Effect Overlaps With Delay + Inline-Block

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having an issue with showing three inline divs through the slide effect in jQuery after a different delay for each div.

Without the different delay it works ok but with the delay, the divs overlap with eachother in the center of the wrapping div and then just magically show up as the three inline divs again (after the effect takes place). I don't know if its because my wrapper div isn't wide enough or not.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#left-service').hide();
    $('#middle-service').hide();
    $('#right-service').hide();

    $('#left-service').delay(500).show('slide', {
        direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#middle-service').delay(1000).show('slide', {
        direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
    $('#right-service').delay(1500).show('slide', {
        direction: 'up'
    }, 1000);
});
```

Essentially what it does is it the `#left-service` slides first in the middle of the wrapper, then the `#middle-service` slides in the middle of the wrapper pushing the `#left-service` left, then the `#right-service` wrapper slides in the middle and moves to the right side.

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hx59/2/)

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle or codpen demo?

Comment: Sorry, just did it. It's in the original question.

Comment: You can see how they overlap before each sliding individually. I was thinking would it be better for this purpose to put the divs inside a table instead of keeping them inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `float: left` to all three will solve the issue.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hx59/3/)

You can remove `display: inline-block` for all three `div's`

CSS

```
#middleside, #rightside, #leftside {
    float: left;
}
```